# The use of the expresssion 首の皮一枚繋がっている + で particle

Tags: particle-で, sentence, reading-comprehension

[image]

This is said at the beginning of the chapter.  The character is contemplating that he managed to finish without his secret leaking out.

As far I understand 首の皮一枚繋がっている  is an expression that means akin to:

" まだわずかな望みが残っていることのたとえ" or " Don't make a mistake again. You're on thin ice" in english

> ばれてないことで首の皮一枚繋がっている

What I don't exactly understand here it's how it's being used in relation to  ばれてないことで?

My understanding of the sentence, from context, is that his secret didn't leak, but he's on thin ice/risking it.

Answer (score 1):

ばれてない**ことで** is literally "**with the fact** that it hasn't come out", but it can be simply interpreted as "since it hasn't come out yet" here. This 首の皮一枚繋がっている is used in a positive sense; "(although I'm on thin ice / hanging by a thread,) I'm still safe at this moment".

> バレてないことで首の皮一枚繋がっているけど、…
>
> Since it hasn't been discovered yet, I'm still hanging by a thread for now, but (I'm virtually finished)